# Obtain value from a column based off condition in another column in R?

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data table like this:

```
DT <- data.table(score=c(78, 93, 88, 50), IQ=c(101, 95, 89, 90))

# DT output
score, IQ
78, 101
93, 95
88, 89
50, 90
```

I want to obtain the `score` at which `IQ` is the highest, e.g. here `max(IQ)=101` so we would get 78.

Is there a way to do this by creating a new table and using:

```
new_DT <- DT[, list(scoreMaxIQ = ...)]
```

i.e. inside `list(...)` we create a new variable `scoreMaxIQ` for the score at which IQ is the highest?

Comment: `DT[IQ==max(IQ)]`

Comment: This seems to return the whole row where IQ is max (weirdly, it returns the 2nd row where IQ=95 instead of the first row where IQ=101). Is there a way to return only the score where IQ is max?

Comment: Why are you using quotes if you intend numeric values? In the base solution, you should use `which.max` instead of `max`.

Comment: @nicola my fault, I changed them to numeric values. Have you seen my edit to the bottom of the question? If it's possible to put this new variable into the `list()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```
DT[,.(IQ, score,maxIQ = IQ[which.max(IQ)],scoreMaxIQ =score[which.max(IQ)] )]

    IQ score maxIQ scoreMaxIQ
1: 101    78   101         78
2:  95    93   101         78
3:  89    88   101         78
4:  90    50   101         78
```

Note the necessary conversion to numeric because `"101"<"95"` in character mode.

Comment: Is there a way to do this by creating a new table and using: `new_DT <- DT[, list(...)]`? i.e. inside `list(...)` we create a new variable `abc` for the score at which IQ is the highest?

Comment: How would this look inside `list()`?

Comment: in `data.table`, `.()` is equivalent to `list()`,see https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html

Comment: just to clarify, should `scoreMaxIQ =score[which.max(IQ)` actually be `scoreMaxIQ =score[which.max(maxIQ)` ? i.e. change IQ to maxIQ inside which.max()

Comment: A shown by the results, the initial version is correct. `which.max(IQ)` gives the index of the row where `IQ` is max.